# Check if element is list or another object

Tags: python

I've got an object which contains an element named "companies".
This element can either be a list of objects or just a single object (not contained within a list).

I would like to run through all companies, but this example fails if the element "companies" is just a single item (not contained within a list):

```
for company in companies:
```

I've tried to test before the for-loop, such as:

```
if type(companies['company']) is list:
    # do your thing
```

but that fails as well.

Can anyone help?

Comment: you have to turn the JSON string back into a python object first.

Comment: If you are literally typing `if type(companies['company'] is list:`, the reason why it's not working is because you omitted a close-parenthesis - it should be `if type(companies['company']) is list:`  But DanielRoseman's solution of using `isinstance` is better.

Comment: Say @T.J.Crowder, your edit [is under discussion here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284147/what-to-do-with-this-edit). Care to drop by and provide your reasoning?

Comment: I removed "JSON" from the question as JSON is unrelated to the question, which is just about objects, not "JSON objects". [More here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284151/157247).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Firstly, that's a really horrible way to structure data, and you should complain to whoever creates it. If an item can be a list, it should *always* be a list, even if that list just contains one element.

However, the code you have shown should work - although a better way to do it is `if isinstance(companies['company'], list)`. If that's still not working, you will need to show the data, and the exact code that's using it.

Comment: I second it's a horrible way to structure data and that `isinstance` is a better approach. I'll just add for the OP that probably doing: `if not isinstance(companies['company'], list): companies['company'] = [companies['company']]` might be worth doing - thus avoiding special casing loops etc...

Comment: Unfortunately it's not me who have structured it that way, it's from Yahoo's API. So Yahoo is returning such JSON.

Comment: Somehow isinstance worked, my previous (with the correct amount of close-parenthesis) still fails.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a list from a non-list for non-conditional use of "for ... in ...".

```
companies = list(companies)
for company in companies:
    # use "company" in some way
```